# asp.net core 5 Ubuntu 20.04 TLS v1 Sql

Tags: sql-server-2014, ubuntu-20.04, asp.net-core-5.0

I cannot enable TSL v1 on this, asp.net runtime 5.0.2-focal, docker image. This uses ubuntu 20.04. It needs to connection to old Sql server 14 Database

I've append this to the end of the openssl.cnf file, via the dockerfile, but it doesn't work (I've seen it work on previous version of linux). Is there something else that needs to be configured to get this working?

```
openssl_conf = default_conf

[ default_conf ]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ ssl_sect ]
system_default = system_default_sect

[ system_default_sect ]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

docker file extract

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.2-focal AS runtime
RUN echo "" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "openssl_conf = default_conf" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "[ default_conf ]" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "ssl_conf = ssl_sect" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "[ ssl_sect ]" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "system_default = system_default_sect" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "[ system_default_sect ]" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "MinProtocol = TLSv1" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
RUN echo "CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1" >> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Comment: Why do you *want* to use TLS 1.0 at all? TLS 1.0 and 1.1 have been basically deprecated by everything now.

Comment: I know but it's out of my control. The database will get migrated/upgrded this year. But I would to move to .netcore 5 now.

Comment: SQL Server version 14 (2017) supports TLS1.2 though; as does SQL Server 2012+. I think even 2008 gained support for it. If you're using a version that doesn't support TLS 1.2 you're busing a completely unsupported version of SQL Server. *That's* your real problem.

Comment: I like say I know. Do you have answer to the question posed though?

Comment: @PaulMcTigue were you able to get around this issue?